# SQL SERVER - Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: sql, sql-server

i got a little problem in my SQL Query. The following error is :

```
 Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

And here is my SQL Query

```
ALTER PROC sp_savepresence
@Username char(20),
@Image text
AS
BEGIN
------------
DECLARE  @PresStatus CHAR,
         @DateDiff INT,
         @ClockIn DATETIME,
         @InsertData varchar(20) = 'TranSavePresence';
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Username FROM PresenceTransaction WHERE Username=@Username AND ClockOut IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION @InsertData
                INSERT INTO PresenceTransaction
                (
                    Username,
                    [Image],
                    PresenceStatus,
                    WorkHour,
                    ClockIn,
                    ClockOut
                )
                VALUES
                (
                    @Username,
                    @Image,
                    'N',
                    0,
                    getdate(),
                    NULL
                )
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @ClockIn = ClockIn, @DateDiff = DateDiff(MINUTE, @ClockIn, getDate()) FROM PresenceTransaction WHERE Username=@Username AND ClockOut IS NULL AND PresenceStatus = 'N'
    IF @DateDiff IS NOT NULL    
    BEGIN
        SELECT @PresStatus = 'P'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @PresStatus='N'
    END

    UPDATE PresenceTransaction 
        SET  
            PresenceStatus = @PresStatus,   
            WorkHour = @DateDiff,
            ClockOut = getDate()
        WHERE Username=@Username AND ClockOut IS NULL AND PresenceStatus = 'N'
END

------------
IF(@@Error <> 0)
BEGIN
    PRINT @@Error
    Rollback Tran @InsertData
    SELECT @@Error AS [Status]
END
ELSE    
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRAN @InsertData
    SELECT 'True' AS [Status]
END
END
GO
```

I have already read from some articles over the Internet, and some of articles, tell me to tune up my query. But i don't know where's the error point or maybe deadlock point, and I don't know how to tune up my query code. Thanks :)

Comment: If you want to check for the presence of a row and, based on the result, do some other work then it should all be inside one transaction. Otherwise row could be created between the time you checked and the time you attempt the INSERT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stored procedure code conditionally starts a transaction, but commits if there was no error, rather than also checking if a transaction is in progress. See [`@@TRANCOUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx).

The fact you are trying to use a named transaction suggests there are other transactions likely to be active.  Unless you are a guru (*and I'm not*) I would strongly suggest not using named nested transactions. It is hard to get right and often leads to confusing, hard to maintain code.

Comment: i've tried to check using @@TRANCOUNT and it returned 3 as result.

Comment: Then you also have other problems.  The fact you are trying to use a named transaction suggests there are other transaction likely to be present? Unless you are a guru (and I'm not) don't use named nested transactions

Comment: would you mind to help me to edit my cruel code ? So I can understand where my problem is. Honestly i'm a new comer in SQL.

Comment: Wow great, thanks @MitchWheat. I have to put the BEGIN TRANSACTION above IF, in order it matches with the Rollback or Commit. Thank you guys. :)